# position:fixed iOS double tap to top

Tags: javascript, ios, css, responsive-design

Kind of a noob question: I have been working on this website: http://alexe.ro/beta

Is there any way, on an iPhone, to keep the position:fixed of the menu (activated by the toggle hamburger icon), while keeping the 'tap to top' functionality?

If you need any more information, I am here. Thank you in advance.

**Later Edit:** JavaScript answers welcome, but not jQuery, since I wanted to avoid it for this particular project (reason: learning JavaScript).

Comment: did you try with top:0;

Comment: That is not the issue.